# PHP Loop through Multidimensional to Onedimentional Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have some javascript that, through ajax, passes some content to a PHP controller. What it passes is a multidimentional array, for example:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [a] => - Item 1.1
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
      [a] => - Item 1.2
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
      [a] => - Item 1.3
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
      [b] => - Item 2.1
    )

  [4] => Array
    (
      [b] => - Item 2.2
    )

  [5] => Array
    (
      [b] => - Item 2.3
    )

  [6] => Array
    (
      [b] => - Item 2.4
    )

  [7] => Array
    (
      [c] => - Item 3.1
    )

  [8] => Array
    (
      [c] => - Item 3.2
    )
...
)
```

About the array: `0, 1, 2`, etc.. are automatically made by the array. The letters `a, b, c`, etc.. are categories for content in the html, or basically `.classes`. Here's some of my JavaScript for more information:

```
$("div[data-category]").each(function() {

    $cat = $(this).data("category");

    $str = $(this).siblings().each(function() {

        if ($(this).children().hasClass("selected")) {
            var response = {};
            response[$cat] = $(this).children().data("response-text") + "\n";
            responses.push(response);
        ...
        }
    });
});
```

My end goal is to have an array that's

```
Array (
  [a] => - Item 1.1 \n Item 1.2 \n Item 1.3
  [b] => - Item 2.1 \n Item 2.2 \n Item 2.3 \n Item 2.4
  [c] => - Item 3.1 \n Item 3.2
)
```

So I could do this in my JavaScript (which I probably should) or I can just leave the JavaScript as is, and create a loops in PHP to loop through the array, get all sub-keys that are say, `a`, concatenate all the `a`'s together (with `\n` new lines for each individual), then has a one dimensional array.

Please suggest either a PHP loop solution or a JavaScript solution that will make the array I want.

===== EDIT =====

**My Solution Below**

(In the answers section)

Comment: The obligatory: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, so far I've tried different variations of array pushes on `responses` in the JS, and putting `responses` push outside the `if` statement. I'm still working more towards a solution on the JavaScript side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered a super easy fix on the JavaScript side:

Instead of `var responses = [];` declared:

```
var responses = {
    a: "",
    b: "",
    c: "",
    d: "",
    e: "",
    f: "",
    g: ""
};
```

Then I simply just accessed the main array directly, and used `+=` to continue adding on to the specific key, each time the loop goes:

```
$("div[data-category]").each(function() {

    $cat = $(this).data("category");

    $str = $(this).siblings().each(function() {

        if ($(this).children().hasClass("selected")) {
            // NEW CODE-SOLUTION BELOW
            responses[$cat] += $(this).children().data("response-text") + "\n";
        ...
        }
    });
});
```

Which now produces this format:

```
Array (
  [a] => - Item 1.1
        - Item 1.2
        - Item 1.3
  [b] => - Item 2.1
        - Item 2.2
        - Item 2.3
        - Item 2.4
  [c] => - Item 3.1
        - Item 3.2
)
```

So a better fix on the JavaScript side, instead of sending a messed up array to the PHP controller, and having to "fix" it there.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't create the newline separated entries as you asked for, but I really don't believe in hardcoding formatting into data anway. You can easily loop over the entries to create what you want.

```
var data = [
    {a: "Item 1.1"},
    {a: "Item 1.2"},
    {a: "Item 1.3"},
    {b: "Item 2.1"},
    {b: "Item 2.2"},
    {b: "Item 2.3"},
    {b: "Item 2.4"},
    {c: "Item 3.1"},
    {c: "Item 3.1"},
];

var result = {};

for (var index in data) {
  for (var item in data[index]) {
    if (result[item] === undefined) {
        result[item] = [];
    }
    result[item].push(data[index][item]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oru62n80/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = [
    ['a' => '- Item 1.1'],
    ['a' => '- Item 1.2'],
    ['a' => '- Item 1.3'],
    ['b' => '- Item 2.1'],
    ['b' => '- Item 2.2'],
    ['b' => '- Item 2.3'],
    ['b' => '- Item 2.4'],
    ['c' => '- Item 3.1'],
    ['c' => '- Item 3.2'],
];

$uniqueKeys = [];
$callback = function ($item) use (&$uniqueKeys) {
    $uniqueKeys[] = array_keys($item)[0];
};

array_map($callback, $data);

$uniqueKeys = array_unique($uniqueKeys);

$combinedData = [];

foreach ($uniqueKeys as $key){
    $combinedData[$key] = implode(' \n ', array_column($data, $key));
}

var_dump($combinedData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop in PHP :

```
foreach($array as $subArray){
    foreach($subArray as $val){
        $newArray[] = $val;
    }
}
```

In other way you can use PHP function :

```
$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```